# How to get EnumMember to work in ASP.net 5 with Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-core

I have the released version of Visual Studio 2015 and ASP.NET 5 Beta 6 installed.  I am trying to convert an existing web site to the new ASP.net and have a simple enum for US states where I use EnumMember for the state full name.

Problem is that I need System.Runtime.Serialization for this and I tried including it in the project.json without any luck.  All the hits I get on the web are from the VS 2015 beta from last year.

I added "System.Runtime.Serialization": "4.0.10.0" to the dependencies section, but I get an compile error DNX 4.5.1 error : The dependency System.Runtime.Serialization >= 4.0.10.0 could not be resolved.

What am I missing?  It used to be easy to add system references, so I must be missing something.  The intellisense helped with the name, but did not give any help with the version.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Right click on your project -> Add -> Reference.. -> Assemblies -> Mark System.Runtime.Serialization (i have 4.0.0.0 version ) -> Ok